# Set IP address and port of Nsqlookupd in docker compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nsq

Is there a way to manually set the lookupd connection of the NSQd Node in the docker compose file through the command: \nsq?

Below is the docker-compose file provided by nsq

```
    version: '3'
services:
  nsqlookupd:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqlookupd
    ports:
      - "4160"
      - "4161"
  nsqd:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqd --lookupd-tcp-address=nsqlookupd:4160
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookupd
    ports:
      - "4150"
      - "4151"
  nsqadmin:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqadmin --lookupd-http-address=nsqlookupd:4161
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookupd  
    ports:
      - "4171"
```

Comment: no idea. post here your Dockerfile

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev the goal is to manually set the lookupconnection (ip:port) of the broadcast address